# Fragment onActivityResult requestCode comparison fails

Tags: android, variables, android-intent, fragment

i have a fragment hosted by a Viewpager in a FragmentActivity.

i make an Intent in that fragment and start a new Activity

```
...
private static final int INSERT_SPOT = 0;

public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {      
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SpotAddActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.SPOTLAT, point.latitude);
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.SPOTLNG, point.longitude);
    startActivityForResult(intent, INSERT_SPOT);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {on
    //@TODO why doesnt that work?
    if (requestCode == INSERT_SPOT) {
        int test = requestCode; 
    }
}
```

I can see in the debugger that onActivityResult() is called, but the comparison of the requestCode (which is 0 says the debugger) to my contant fails. 
I'm confused, how can that fail?

regards

Comment: can you debug and see what is the requestCode you are getting back ?

Comment: yes, as mentioned, the debug variable window says its 0

Comment: can you change the value of your requestCode to something other than 0  and see what you will get

Comment: i tried it with 1. Same result

Comment: there should be nothing wrong, try to do more logging inside the onActivityResult mothod